# Switching between views

Tags: android, view, switching

I am a beginner in android, what I have to do is I have an audio playing with images. Also in the bottom bar, I have a button to map. Now I need to change my view to the map when clicked on map button. But the audio should not be stopped, it should keep playing in the background.

Can any one tell me the way to do this?

Thanks in advance,

Tejaswi

Comment: For audio play in background you have to use service....so go for it!!

Answer (score 0):

Use [ViewAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewAnimator.html) to switch between views without changing activity.